# Search in a row wise and column wise N x M sorted matrix

Tags: java, search

Given a matrix of integers A of size N x M and an integer B.
In the given matrix every row and column is sorted in increasing order. Find and return the position of B in the matrix in the given form:

1. If A[i][j] = B then return (i * 1009 + j)
2. If B is not present return -1.

My solution:

```
    public static int solve(int[][] A, int B) {
    int N = A.length;
    int i = 0;
    int j = N - 1;
    while (i < N && j >= 0) {
        if (A[i][j] == B) {
            System.out.println("number found");
            return (i * 1009 + j);
        }
        if (A[i][j] > B) {
            j--;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("number not found");
    return (-1);
}
```

doesn't work when the matrix isn't NxN. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index of j should be valid, otherwise it will not work for N X M matrix

```java
int j = A[0].length - 1;
```